# Distribute union of arrow function argument(s) in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions, cartesian-product, union-types

I'll set out my entire thought process first before getting to the question -- partly because a search engine might pick up on some keywords, and also so that answer givers don't have to elaborate unnecessarily.

In TypeScript, a union type `U` of two types `A` and `B` looks like

```
type U = A | B;
```

This means that *a value of type `U` can be of type `A` or `B`*.

Let's say I want to define an arrow function type `F` with two parameters (`x` of type `X` and `y` of type `Y`) that returns a value of type `Z`. That looks like:

```
type F = (x: X, y: Y) => Z;   // (1)
```

So far so good. However, now I want *functions of type `F` to accept either `X1` or `X2` as the type of their first argument, and `Y1` or `Y2` as the type of their second argument*. From the above, intuition would suggest

```
type F = (x: X1|X2, y: Y1|Y2) => Z;   // (2)
```

... but this is wrong! A value of type `(x: X1, y: Y1) => Z` is not assignable to a value of type `F`, because the above TypeScript type `F` stands for *functions that have the union type `X1|X2` as the type of their first argument, and the union type `Y1|Y2` as the type of their second argument*. Indeed, (2) is equivalent to:

```
type Xs = X1 | X2;
type Ys = Y1 | Y2;
type F = (x: Xs, y: Ys) => Z;   // (3), equivalent to (2)
```

Manually, our problem is solved by instead writing

```
type F = ( (x: X1, y: Y1) => Z ) | ( (x: X1, y: Y2) => Z ) | ( (x: X2, y: Y1) => Z ) | ( (x: X2, y: Y2) => Z )  // (4)
```

The union of arguments has been replaced by a union of functions with the former union's types distributed over them. It looks a bit like a Cartesian product of TypeScript types, if you will.

Here's my problem: ***I** only know the union types of the acceptable argument types (`Xs` and `Ys`)*, so I cannot manually write out such a Cartesian product in advance. Going back to my first line of code (the definition of type `U`), clearly, if only `U` was given without `A` and `B`, you could still use it to mean *any one of the types in the union will do*. How can I specify *any one of the types in the union will do for the type definition of the argument(s) of the arrow function*?

Comment: This should be doable, but is it useful? You won't be able to tell which type of function you have at runtime, unless these functions are tagged somehow (e.g. give them a property which says which type of argument they accept). You can't do some sort of `typeof` check on a function to figure out which type of argument to give it. If you intend to only supply arguments that are acceptable to all possible function types you might have, then `(x: X1 & X2, y: Y1 & Y2) => Z` is the function type you would want.

Comment: That's true. I indeed aim to have such a tag stored along with the functions.

Comment: In that case, wouldn't you need to include the tag as part of the union type declaration, so that it's a tagged union? Otherwise the tag isn't guaranteed to match what argument types the function accepts.

Comment: Probably, yes, although that would be adding additional complexity, which the person giving an answer might not want to deal with. I'm trying to keep things as un-hacky as possible (because it seems like what I'm asking _should_ be doable in an un-hacky way). It's really a probe as to whether I'm missing one of the TypeScript basics.

Comment: You don't seem to be missing anything basic, I'm just asking to make sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. An answer which doesn't create a tagged union may not be easy to convert into one which does.

Comment: In any case, assume that an intersection like in your first comment is not something I'm looking for (or, alternatively, that those intersections are always empty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do it for functions with two arguments: I've assumed you want the result to be a tagged union, so that you can know what type of arguments to pass to the function at runtime.

In order to describe the tags for each parameters' union types, it accepts objects like `{x1: X1, x2: X2}` so that `'x1'` and `'x2'` become the tags for the `X` union, and the result uses tags like `'x1-y1'`. It would be straightforward to add properties like `xTag: Xi, yTag: Yi` if you need to preserve the original tags.

```
type CreateTaggedUnionOf2Functions<X, Y, T> = {
    [Xi in keyof X]: {
        [Yi in keyof Y]: {
            tag: `${Xi & string}-${Yi & string}`,
            func: (x: X[Xi], y: Y[Yi]) => T
        }
    }[keyof Y]
}[keyof X]


// --- Test ---
type Test = CreateTaggedUnionOf2Functions<{x1: X1, x2: X2}, {y1: Y1, y2: Y2}, Z>
/* equivalent to:
type Test = {tag: "x1-y1", func: (x: X1, y: Y1) => Z}
          | {tag: "x1-y2", func: (x: X1, y: Y2) => Z}
          | {tag: "x2-y1", func: (x: X2, y: Y1) => Z}
          | {tag: "x2-y2", func: (x: X2, y: Y2) => Z}
*/
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCAVRBzDEAmBVAOwEsB7AgeQDMAmAMQFcCBjYUggZwB4ANAGigCa-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)

I was not satisfied with writing a solution which works specifically and only for functions with two parameters, so here is a generalised version: it is rather complicated, but less so than I thought it might be. Perhaps it can be simplified somehow.

```
// --- Implementation ---
type CreateTaggedUnion<A extends any[]>
    = A extends [infer X]
    ? {
        [Xi in keyof X]: {tag: Xi, arr: [X[Xi]]}
    }[keyof X]
    : A extends [infer X, ...infer Y]
    ? {
        [Xi in keyof X]: CreateTagMap<Y> extends infer U ? {
            [Yi in keyof U]: {
                tag: `${Xi & string}-${Yi & string}`,
                arr: U[Yi] extends any[] ? [X[Xi], ...U[Yi]] : never
            }
        }[keyof U] : never
    }[keyof X]
    : never

type CreateTagMap<A extends any[]>
    = CreateTaggedUnion<A> extends infer U
    ? [U] extends [{tag: infer K, arr: any}]
    ? {[Ki in K & string]: (U & {tag: Ki})['arr']}
    : never
    : never

type CreateTaggedUnionOfFunctions<A extends any[], R>
    = CreateTagMap<A> extends infer U
    ? {
        [K in keyof U]: U[K] extends any[] ? {tag: K, func: (...args: U[K]) => R} : never
    }[keyof U]
    : never


// --- Tests ---
interface X1 {x: 1}
interface X2 {x: 2}
interface Y1 {y: 1}
interface Y2 {y: 2}
interface Z1 {z: 1}
interface Z2 {z: 2}
interface O {o: 3}

type TestM = CreateTagMap<[{x1: X1, x2: X2}, {y1: Y1, y2: Y2}, {z1: Z1, z2: Z2}]>
/** equivalent to TypeScript type:
 * type TestM = {
 *   "x1-y1-z1": [X1, Y1, Z1];
 *   "x1-y1-z2": [X1, Y1, Z2];
 *   "x1-y2-z1": [X1, Y2, Z1];
 *   "x1-y2-z2": [X1, Y2, Z2];
 *   "x2-y1-z1": [X2, Y1, Z1];
 *   "x2-y1-z2": [X2, Y1, Z2];
 *   "x2-y2-z1": [X2, Y2, Z1];
 *   "x2-y2-z2": [X2, Y2, Z2];
 * }
 */
type TestU = CreateTaggedUnion<[{x1: X1, x2: X2}, {y1: Y1, y2: Y2}, {z1: Z1, z2: Z2}]>
/** equivalent to TypeScript type:
 * type TestU = {
 *   tag: "x1-y1-z1";
 *   arr: [X1, Y1, Z1];
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x1-y1-z2";
 *   arr: [X1, Y1, Z2];
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x1-y2-z1";
 *   arr: [X1, Y2, Z1];
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x1-y2-z2";
 *   arr: [X1, Y2, Z2];
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x2-y1-z1";
 *   arr: [X2, Y1, Z1];
 * } | ...
 */
type TestF = CreateTaggedUnionOfFunctions<[{x1: X1, x2: X2}, {y1: Y1, y2: Y2}, {z1: Z1, z2: Z2}], O>
/** equivalent to TypeScript type:
 * type TestF = {
 *   tag: "x1-y1-z1";
 *   func: (args_0: X1, args_1: Y1, args_2: Z1) => O;
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x1-y1-z2";
 *   func: (args_0: X1, args_1: Y1, args_2: Z2) => O;
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x1-y2-z1";
 *   func: (args_0: X1, args_1: Y2, args_2: Z1) => O;
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x1-y2-z2";
 *   func: (args_0: X1, args_1: Y2, args_2: Z2) => O;
 * } | {
 *   tag: "x2-y1-z1";
 *   func: (args_0: X2, args_1: Y1, args_2: Z1) => O;
 * } | ...
 */
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgThAhsCAVRBzDEAmBVAOwEsB7AgHgEEoIAPFAnAZykQJAG0BdAPgCgogqAF4o1Og2ZQORAgDMIcKAA0uAoQH4oAb3VChHZUSiyoAawggSclVwBcO4JgdGANKzhwHhw0S5cAXz0oAI4LKxtVYIdxeghGFhl5RRV3ADoM2QUlAE01fS1dfX1fEwJzS2tbB3gkFHQMAFlEMHIcnho4hLLsqDwoQuDigxzjU3CqvHsdIeHipwwHAAMAEm0jKAAyKCZgOFkMAIBaNdGtnb2DgKXXWbmhRE8HPA5Rrk7JFjZOd60fIy46QyLze7wcBAgADdFHdikF7qEJjYplBwVCYfpEZVIvkhGjoXA+HxQJBYAhkGhMM1WrFPqx2Nx+PpRLUKQ1sPhiGQqB0JPEpFkUnhgn8UXzuhxtAsHIKlABpdyPLz0kABXGCQocOVjcpy867fYEDDTAAU-W2UucUG1AQAlBwAORKh2BaJQCEEt0emHE8DQVn1TAcwikAgAeTkADEAK4EADGwFDTCoH35XwZgKgACUmUIWeTA00WjzU91ZX0RTN7lqyhUIn1pi85e9xVJvtwBo4rQqoHJY3GHCaMmlHhgmM8tVxbSIOlmAqj3ejCZiwtiG16l0S+AB6bdQFC7Jh8WQoOByRBx6DKACMOloDmvQRPinPl5UACY7w530+CKfX9AOS3toIAPr+-4XoBn4gd+4EvpBUAAFrAQAXmBx5-vBb6IdBaFQD+GEQW+YY6CQDgAMxBL6pKoBAuyNCIZJ1JSRatJKtDXi417uLQ74uD+7ggZxUBAe4IB8SJAk6ChwnIe4KESThar8NuABUqk0AAjtGRCQogAA28TAPuJBQKgfoAMpxvsYDGSSEB2AIGn2WZdHAAxohFBpggAEQcUcIDXkcMk+d4N7uKJSHXlwADcTlCH5QWBcF76hdI4UidxSHvrF8W+f54nBdeaWGFlOTvu4yG5VA3lQIlAXvilJUZeVlU5XFNUJbxAVBSFYUVZllXRR1tV+Y1yUKc1A2RTh1Wjd1hV9el00DVVI1deNjWTf1EWre18Xwqp27UdAtG7P0+bMeyuAhty7HCRlvH8QEgmBQ4kXie9UnaDJDhyVACl-T+vA7upWk6Xphl-iZZmWdZRC2fufqOZ1LlncAF1VrV0p1QVvXFetghKmFZVZWtB1QAAPljQg4-VE2pYTHjKqVEVk-tnXztTXm01a9NbQTeXMyTu1DXNIRUzTgh0wVW2M0LxPpWVe3i1zUv7nzC34z5TOK4Y01k8NFPU8OTnHWjbmRoxAYscGXLhlG-aJmQyb3VxPESco31vYNUCfZJL3SbJWWA9laruGGKlgxA2m6QZRkw+ZkBWTZdnI-FFu7FbnlCzLSXa0zfbxoOo5MAA+gADO7HhjmXwmRaXZeKde07CB0YbrWrPPS5r+dNYX-Yl3AtdVyoWWN-X4-D+Xinvq37ed5L3ca4suNJQLOtC0XA5QCajejxlE9fYq09N39LczlAHfG+recNf3W+D7v+-V0fkkn7Xs-z1fi-c7nmvjQLo-Yuz9T4HwGm-Bup9m7f2vpzSWpsarHSAA)

Comment: Awesome! I've added the tests from the second playground to your code sample here, if that's alright.